# How to get the desired data/values from the xml datatable?

Tags: android, xml, server, android-xmlpullparser

Hi I am working on a client/server app. And I am able to get the response from the server in the xml format. but now I have to sort out or filter the data. I am using the following code to get the reply from the server and it is working fine

```
    package com.example.KsoapExample;

import android.util.Log;
import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Sashen
 * Date: 12/17/13
 * Time: 10:58 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class SoapRequests {

    private static final boolean DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE = true;
    //
    private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL ="http://192.168.0.7/xx/service.asmx";
     private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String SESSION_ID;
    public static String Toaster=null ;

    private final void testHttpResponse(HttpTransportSE ht) {
        ht.debug = DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
        if (DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE) {
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "Request XML:\n" + ht.requestDump);
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "\n\n\nResponse XML:\n" + ht.responseDump)
            ;
            Toaster=ht.responseDump;
        }
    }

    public String getCelsiusConversion(String fValue) {
        String data = null;
        String methodname = "GetServerStatus";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);
        request.addProperty("username", "admin");
        request.addProperty("password", "admin");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodname, envelope);
            testHttpResponse(ht);
            SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            List<HeaderProperty> COOKIE_HEADER = (List<HeaderProperty>) ht.getServiceConnection().getResponseProperties();

            for (int i = 0; i < COOKIE_HEADER.size(); i++) {
                String key = COOKIE_HEADER.get(i).getKey();
                String value = COOKIE_HEADER.get(i).getValue();

                if (key != null && key.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
                    SoapRequests.SESSION_ID = value.trim();
                    Log.v("SOAP RETURNCookiee", "Cookie :" + SoapRequests.SESSION_ID);
                    break;
                }
            }
            data = resultsString.toString();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception q) {
            q.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        return envelope;
    }

    private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,MAIN_REQUEST_URL,60000);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");
        return ht;
    }

    private final List<HeaderProperty> getHeader() {
        List<HeaderProperty> header = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        HeaderProperty headerPropertyObj = new HeaderProperty("cookie", SoapRequests.SESSION_ID);
        header.add(headerPropertyObj);
        return header;
    }
}
```

and in log I can see the server is giving me data and also I am taking that data into a text field but it looks like the following

```
 <NewDataSet>
 <Table>
 <ServerStatus>Active</ServerStatus >
 </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Where as I want to take out and to show only "ServerStatus"that is eiter Active,Inactive etc. I have seen many techniques such as pullparser but they have there own Http connect method which I do not want to use. So Now tell me how to do that. Please help

I am getting the response and displaying it in textfield it is like

```
 <NewDataSet>
    <Table1>
    <ServerStatus>Standby</ServerStatus>
    </Table1>
    </NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you got the reply from the server and stored it in `result`.

```
String result = "<NewDataSet><Table><ServerStatus>Active</ServerStatus></Table></NewDataSet>";

  String status = "error";

  Document dom = null;
  DocumentBuilder builder;
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
  try {
    InputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    dom = builder.parse(resultStream);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if(dom != null) {
    NodeList nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName("Table");
    for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {
      Node node = nodeList.item(itr);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) node;
        status = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ServerStatus").item(0).getTextContent();
      }
    }
  }
  Log.d(TAG, status);
```

Imports:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

Comment: its giving me error on this line on this part result.getBytes("UTF-8") . error is unsupportedencoding exception

Comment: and please also tell me what should i import for this type of code segment, weather it should be import org.w3c.dom.Document; OR import org.kxml2.kdom.Document;  I think that it is error due to wrong import

Comment: I edited the answer. You have to write that piece of code in _try catch_ block. You need to import _org.w3c.dom.Document_.

Comment: I am getting the status null

Comment: and in log I got the following response. Would it be working with yur code :
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetServerStatusResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetServerStatusResult>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
    &lt;Table1&gt;
    &lt;ServerStatus&gt;Standby&lt;/ServerStatus&gt;
    &lt;/Table1&gt;
    &lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</GetServerStatusResult></GetServerStatusResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: The code will not work with the response you are getting. Where is the status in the response? Update your question with the response.

Comment: What do you mean by _server is giving me data which looks like_ `<NewDataSet>
 <Table>
 <ServerStatus>Active</ServerStatus >
 </Table>
</NewDataSet>`  in the question?

Comment: I have re edit the question. 
I am getting the response/xml from the server just like
<NewDataSet>
    <Table1>  and the code you shared is not working and whereas if I put your xml string that you have shown in answer I mean which you are saving in result If I do that using hard coding it is working and taking out the answer as active but this is not the case I want to take out status given by the server
    <ServerStatus>Standby</ServerStatus>
    </Table1>
    </NewDataSet>

Comment: after reading thoroughly I have reached to a point that I am getting Element name as "Table1" not only Table As I posted in question but after figuring that out I am not able to get my require answer

Comment: So you got response as <NewDataSet><Table1><ServerStatus>Standby</ServerStatus></Table1></NewDataSet>. Assume this as _result_ in the above answer. `String result = "<NewDataSet><Table1><ServerStatus>Standby</ServerStatus></Table1></NewDataSet>"` Also, change `Table` with `Table1`.

Comment: I have done this already as i stated above but its still not working

Comment: I don't know why...it's working for me. Are you printing the status? Look at the edited answer.

Comment: Yes I am doing this and its giving me null